# Heuristic function prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a problem which is [1,2,3,0,4,5,6] and the goal is [4,5,6,0,1,2,3] and the Heuristic function
is to calculate misplaced for 4,5,6 tile in position of 1,2,3 tile so when I try to add the condition for head >3 it always false

```
getHeuristic([], 0, []):-!.
% here it is calculated as number of misplaced numbers for 4,5,6 only
% ( so if Head = Head and value greater than 3 its correct so
% don't count it)
getHeuristic([H|T1],V,[H|T2]):-!,
    H>3,
    getHeuristic(T1,V, T2).
getHeuristic([_|T1],H,[_|T2]):-
    getHeuristic(T1,TH, T2),
    H is TH + 1.
```

Comment: It is hard to guess what you want to do. Can you explain the problem better?

Comment: I have a list which is [1,2,3,0,4,5,6] and the goal to swap 4,5,6 with 1,2,3 so [4,5,6,0,1,2,3]
the  Heuristic function is to calculate the misplaced for only 4,5,6 so at the begin the h(n)=3

Comment: if I find tile (4,5,6) in wrong place to tile(1,2,3) then count it.

Comment: do you need the whole code ?

Comment: No need for whole code but if I understand correctly, the problem statement is to swap sub-sequence `[1,2,3]` with sub-sequence `[4,5,6]` because ... they are separated with a 0 which is out-of-sequence for `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`? Is that correct? You do not need a heuristic for this (a "heuristic" being a set of "good enough" rules that are "often correct" and help you make progress if full evaluation of a situation is too costly). This seems like a deterministic problem.

Comment: its a actually a tile like 8 puzzle problem but this is 1D problem where I can only move the 0 tile to left and right only to reach the goal I need to implement a heuristic problem such that it count the number of misplaced for only 4,5,6 so need to count 4,5,6 if they appear at position of 1,2,3

Comment: this heuristic function calculate all misplaced tiles i tried to add condition that check if head >3 but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *heuristic* is a quick way to estimate how close the current state is to the goal state (in the state space).

Let h*(S) be the *cost of an optimal path* from current state S to a goal state G. Then, a heuristic function h(S) is **admissible** if, and only, if:

- 0 ≤ h(S) ≤ h*(S), and
- h(G) = 0.

In other words, an admissible heuristic function must be always **optimistic**!

For example, from the following current state, you need *at least* two "moves" to reach the goal state:

- Current state = `[6,4,5,0,1,2,3]`
- Swap 6 and 4  : `[4,6,5,0,1,2,3]`
- Swap 5 and 6  : `[4,5,6,0,1,2,3]` = Goal state

Notice that, for example, a heuristic function that estimates the cost of an optimal path to reach the goal state `[4,5,6,0,1,2,3]` from the current state `[5,4,6,0,1,2,3]` as at least `2` **is not admissible** (since a unique move - *swap 5 and 4* - is sufficient to correct both positions).

Thus, I think you can do something like this:

```
heuristic(State, Goal, Value) :-
    heuristic(State, Goal, 0, Value).

heuristic([], [], A, A).
heuristic([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], A, V) :-
    (   X < Y
    ->  A1 is A + 1
    ;   A1 is A ),
    heuristic(Xs, Ys, A1, V).
```

Examples:

```
?- heuristic([1,2,3,0,4,5,6], [4,5,6,0,1,2,3], V).
V = 3.

?- heuristic([6,4,5,0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,0,1,2,3], V).
V = 2.

?- heuristic([5,4,6,0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,0,1,2,3], V).
V = 1.

?- heuristic([4,5,6,0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,0,1,2,3], V).
V = 0.
```

**Remark**: The "moves" counted by the heuristic function do not necessarily correspond to the actual moves that cause transitions from states to their successors in the state space (i.e., they are **relaxed moves**).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute a "distance" from the "current state" to the "target state" by counting the number of nonmatching positions:

```
% nmpcount(+CurrentState,+TargetState,?Count)

nmpcount(CurrentState,TargetState,Count) :-
   nmpcount2(CurrentState,TargetState,0,Count).

% nmpcount2(+CurrentState,+TargetState,+CountSoFar,?CountFinal)

nmpcount2([],[],Count,Count).
nmpcount2([X|MoreCS],[X|MoreTS],CountIn,FinalCount) :-
   nmpcount2(MoreCS,MoreTS,CountIn,FinalCount).
nmpcount2([X|MoreCS],[Y|MoreTS],CountIn,FinalCount) :-
   dif(X,Y),
   CountNext is CountIn+1,
   nmpcount2(MoreCS,MoreTS,CountNext,FinalCount).
```